# Datagrid ComboBox Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am trying to bind a combobox in a datagrid to a list of strings, and then save/load this string in a database.

```
public class AMFM    
{
    public AMFM(String str)
    {
        Name = str;
    }
    public String Name;
}
....
List<AMFM> ft = new List<AMFM>();
        AMFM tmp1 = new AMFM("AM");
        AMFM tmp2 = new AMFM("FM");
        ft.Add(tmp1);
        ft.Add(tmp2);
        cbFT.ItemsSource = ft;
```

And my XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="Name" Header="Frequency Type"  
   SelectedValuePath="{Binding Name}" x:Name="cbFT" 
   SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=FrequencyType,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Where FrequencyType is the column name in my database.

Nothing is being displayed in the combobox. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You can't bind to a public variable, it must be a property `public String Name { get; set; }`. There may be other problems though.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
       List<String> ft = new List<String>();     
        ft.Add("am");
        ft.Add("pm");
        cbFT.ItemsSource = ft;
```

XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Frequency Type" x:Name="cbFT"  
     SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=FrequencyType,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```